# Can't start Hyper-V VM - error hypervisor is not running

Tags: windows-10, bios, virtualization, hyper-v, hypervisor

When attempting to start a VM in Hyper-V I am getting the error "Virtual machine 'VM NAME' could not be started because the hypervisor is not running".  I have confirmed that Virtualization is enabled in the BIOS and Execute Disabled Bit is enabled.  I have attempted to run the command:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

as suggested by other threads but that did not resolve the issue.

Other troubleshooting tasks include: disabling VM in BIOS, cold boot, re enable; same with EDB.

CPU is i5-2500k, Mobo is P8z68V Pro on latest BIOS (3603).  OS is Windows 10.

When running system info:

```
Hyper-V Requirements: 
VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
Second Level Address Translation: Yes
Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

I've exhausted all troubleshooting options that I can find, hoping someone can assist.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you reboot?